# Android Constraint Layout showing attribute 'android:layout_constraintWidth_percent' not found

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I searched a lot for this error but ended up seeing that everyone is suggesting of uninstalling android studio and reinstalling it with all sdk work which is not feasible to me. How can we remove this error in a decent way, please refer me to the answer if anyone has already given the right one.

[image]

Comment: You can set 0dp height.

Comment: Tried but it didn't work.

Comment: You have added gradle ?

Comment: @HardikParmar yes I have added

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Please use **app** instead of **android**.

```
app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
```

**Also, Add one constraint property like below:**

```
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
```

or

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

**your_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_temp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: The error has gone but still there is no change in view.

Comment: Please check my Edited answer. You have to set one property of constraintLayout.